# Strange behaviour with Spotify API when accessing a user's saved tracks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, debugging, spotify

I am making a rails app that uses the Spotify API to access a user's Spotify music library. I have been testing the API on my own account, getting a list of my own saved tracks and I have noticed an issue that I cannot seem to get my head around; I don't know if the issue is specific to me or any user's library in particular. The issue is as follows:

I am requesting the user's saved tracks using the rspotify gem with the code:

```
    saved_tracks = spotify_user.saved_tracks(limit: 50)
```

This correctly returns the first 38 tracks from my Spotify account under "Your Music" -> "Songs", but the remaining 12 tracks of the 50 are in a completely random order. (Note I am using remote-pry to help debugging). Compare the two images in the linsk below to see what I am getting at - the order is congruent in both lists up until the 38th track, then I've no idea where the order is coming from.

http://tinypic.com/r/3133rwp/8
*(Spotify screenshot showing the correct order of tracks in "Your Music")*

http://tinypic.com/r/fdf3gk/8
*(Terminal output screenshot using remote-pry to access each track of the request one by one)*

I tested the API on the Spotify Web API console to see whether the rspotify gem was causing issues but this also returns the exact same seemingly random order after track 38, so I think either the API as a bug, my library has something quirky about it, or I'm doing something fundamentally wrong and haven't noticed.

I cannot understand why the API seems to work perfectly up until track 38 in my library, where the "TheSoundYouNeed, Vol. 1" album starts. The only thing I can think of is that this album is a compilation, whereas all other tracks up to that point are just unrelated, independent tracks. Another thing to note is that the same "random" order appearing after track 38 happens each time I use this API, so although it seems random, there obviously is some logic to it that I'm just not seeing.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me get my head around this issue!